# Why does some shared images not show up on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, web-applications

I have a [web app](https://www.papereed.com/player) in which it is possible to share content on Facebook, Twitter etc. This has worked just fine for a long time but lately I have noticed that some images doesn't show up on Facebook and I have no clue why and I haven't been able to see any pattern when they show up and when not. Sometimes an image doesn't show up and then, if I reload the page, it does show up. On twitter, they all show up just fine btw. All images have the same dimensions.

Here is the Facebook profile so yo can see it for yourself: [FB](https://www.facebook.com/papereed/)

Here is a screenshot illustrating the issue. (Checking the 'learn more' section gives no relevant info)

[image: Facebook post with non-working image]

If I do 'share' from this post the image sometimes shows up in the share dialog even though it doesn't show up in the original post.

In the web app code I essentially do this to share:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxx',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.7'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And then:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        href: 'https://www.papereed.com/play/'+_shareableArticle.id
    });
```

When I use the facebook debugger for https://www.papereed.com/play/01acbaff-8a2c-4ba5-a312-afcc08cc4a7d I get a warning for corrupted image, but it doesn't say what is corrupted, and looking at the jpeg nothing seems wrong.

So, any obvious issues with the code that might cause this? (seems unlikely since it do work sometimes) Or where to start to track down this issue? And how to best do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are likely anti-hotlinking/anti-ddos measures at work, that identify the Facebook scraper as a “bot”, and therefor block access. So you will have to configure your bucket policies accordingly to allow it. The FB scraper can be recognized based on the User-Agent header it sends. (But don’t ask me for any specifics, you’ll have to do some research on that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this one off, after having this issue for a few weeks everything suddenly started to work again. Without any change on my side, I assume some internal issue at Facebook.